# May I use full Ubuntu in a not bootable hard drive?

Tags: boot

**May I use full Ubuntu in a not bootable hard drive?**

My hard drive can't boot (320GB). 
I used it just as a storing device.

But then I remember the power of Linux, and thought there could possibly be a way of booting from a flash-drive and then switch to full Ubuntu in the hard drive. Is it possible?

Comment: You want to boot the extra drive, or read its contents?

Comment: Boot. I'm already able to read contents.

Comment: What makes your hard drive non-bootable? 320 MB may be small, but there are distributions that fit entirely in that space. A full Ubuntu won't, but [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.com) will

Comment: I'm sorry. I mistake. It's 320GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, even you can use floppy disc to boot linux. Or you can install lilo or grub on your primary booting hard drive, and configure it that it point to linux from this not booting HD. (is it really only 320MB)?

Comment: 320MB? -> Yes. It's a laptop HD.
It's the only one I have.
I'm a poor man in a poor land.

Comment: I'm not sure if its enough for any modern linux distribution, but you can always try.

Comment: I'm sorry. I mistake. It's 320GB

Comment: I think I can use grub with Puppy Linux which I launch from a flash drive.

Comment: I've successfully installed full  ubuntu 16.04 in the HDD and launched it initiating from a flash-drive. 
I did it using Grub. Thank you.

Comment: I did it using Grub.
¿Will this work also for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Due to you can read contents, so you can use chroot command to change root, then run the system in your external hard drive.

Comment: is "chroot" a ubuntu command? I can't start ubuntu yet.
But someone commented something about installing grub on the primary booting drive. I think I can use grub with Puppy Linux which I launch from a flash drive.

Comment: most linux has chroot command